# Постоянный Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php

Вот такой простой код вызывает ошибку:

> Using $this when not in object context

Возможно ли, что ошибка зарыта в конфигурации самого пхп?

```
public $db;
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->db = new PDO();
    $this->db->prepare('запрос');
}
```

И даже так:

```
public $db = 'some string';

public function indexAction()
{
    echo $this->db;
}
```

Comment: А к какому объекту относится $this? Где создается объект?



Comment: @sargss, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай конструктор:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new PDO();
}
```

Либо ты вызываешь не статичный метод, как

```
Class::method();
```

В то время нужно как:

```
$obj = new Class();
$obj->method();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Возможно ли, что ошибка зарыта в конфигурации самого пхп?

нет

> Вот такой простой код вызывает ошибку:

Если это не обернуто в `class X { ... }`, то его надо обернуть. Если обернуто - ошибка не здесь.